# EF Code First: How to select data included changes before SaveChanges?

Tags: ef-code-first

I can't explain the code. Look at different behavior:

```
        var project = DB.Project.Find(1000111);
        project.MustLinkToMF = false;

        // Includes id = 1000111; MustLinkToMF = false; - From Cache?
        var projects1 = DB.Project.Select(p => p).ToList();

        // Doesn't contain 1000111! - Not From Cache?
        var projects2 = DB.Project.Where(p => p.MustLinkToMF == false).Select(p => p).ToList();

        DB.SaveChanges();
```

How to get cached data, included my changes?
How Can I get projects2 using one simple query **before** SaveChanges?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate through entities in the first level cache:

```
ctx.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(x => x.Entity).OfType<T>()
```

Just replace EntityState.Modified for what you want.
See an example here: https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/entity-framework-code-first-get-entities-from-local-cache-or-the-database